# count of the number of times

Tags: expressions, writing-style, count

I found this expression in a book.

"This is a count of the number of times SomeDB had to
follow an index pointer to the actual document on disk."

It sounds weird to me but I am a non-native speaker.

Is this correct or incorrect or correct but weird?
Could it be said in some better way?

To me, as it stands it sounds equivalent to

"This is a count of the count of times"
or
"This is a number of the number of times"
which are definitely weird.

Comment: 'A count of ...' is fine, if not very common. Putting 'the number' after it smacks slightly of tautology. "This is the number of times SomeDB had to follow an index pointer to the actual document on disk." works; one might assume someone has done the counting.

Comment: Sounds like something a programmer wrote in a code comment.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["number of books" or "book count"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104770/number-of-books-or-book-count)

Comment: @TimLymington How is my question duplicate of this one?

Comment: The duplicate's answer does not address using both "count" and "number".

Answer (score 5):

It is correct, it's even so correct that it can confuse people.

However, database people tend to want to be quite precise in what they say, write and measure.

*Count* can be a verb. You can count things. You can count the apples in this bag.
You can also count the number of times I use the letter E in this answer.

*Count* can also be a noun. Actually, the *result* of the counting in my two examples would give you a count of apples, and a count of a number of times I use the letter E in my answer.

Now, "normal" people would have no problem saying things like:

79 is the number of times you used the letter E in your answer.

*But* the database guys will tell you: the number of times that you use the letter E is a set of objects, just like those apples in your bag!
And you would not say

12 is the apples in this bag.

That I use the word *number* does not mean I can leave out that fact that I am counting.

In your database, the *count* of the number of times that index-pointer was used is actual *data*. It is a property, it can be stored, etc.

However, the number of times the index pointer was used is not actual data. It never really existed in any real way. The only thing we know about it is how many entities there are in the set. And that number of entities is the *count*.

Comment: From math standpoint: "the number of times that you use the letter E is a set of objects" is not really true. This is actually the size of that set, not the set itself. I guess that's what confuses me in your answer (apart from the overall sense of tautology in this expression I quoted). I would agree with that though: "the times that you use the letter E is a set of objects". But anyway, I am asking a language question here, not a math or programming one.

Comment: The times is the set - the number of times is the size of the set - the count of the number of times is the value of the size of the set. Something like that?

Comment: That version makes sense to me ;) Yes.